# render an html element to the browsers viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

This might be out of the scope of this site but I'm trying to figure out how this page: http://www.borngroup.com/ is able to render the gorilla animation where it will expand the width/ height div to the browsers viewport; then after that you can scroll down and see the rest of the pages content.

I've been trying to figure it out using jQuery to get the height and width of the browsers viewport, then set the CSS elements width/height properties accordingly; it was kinda a miserable failure. I then had the idea to render a single element in the DOM using css the hide the rest, and then use JavaScript to detect a mouse scroll down that would then make the rest of the site visible. But, that didn't work as well. ):

Comment: You don't need jQuery: window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight should work.

Comment: it is a video `<video webkit-playsinline="" data-setup="{}" preload="auto" class="vjs-tech" id="big-video-vid_html5_api" style="position: absolute; width: 1349px; height: auto;" autoplay="" src="http://www.borngroup.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Gorilla-master-vid_1_12_1_1.webm"></video>`. width and height are set on resize using the javascript functions above

Comment: Try messing with [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/fufu7ghp/1/).

Comment: Thanks, I know it's a video I was just trying to figure out how to replicate the same effect. Because all my implementations were buggy and didn't quite work as smoothly as the site

Comment: My answer resolve Your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code writen for You. Is fully responsive, adiust width/height for minimal value which can be set. It is based on `window width to video width` and `window height to video height` ratio.
Auto centering working vertical and horizontal.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y9syhw99/2/)

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function (){

    $(window).on('resize', function (){

        var windowWidth = $(window).innerWidth();
        var windowHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
        var videoWidth = $('#video-container video').outerWidth();
        var videoHeight = $('#video-container video').outerHeight();
        var widthRatio = windowWidth/videoWidth;
        var heightRatio = windowHeight/videoHeight;

        if((widthRatio > heightRatio) || (widthRatio == heightRatio)){

            $('#video-container video').css({

                'width':    windowWidth,
                'height':   'auto'
            });
        }
        else{

            $('#video-container video').css({

                'width':    'auto',
                'height':   windowHeight
            });
        }

        var newVideoWidth = $('#video-container video').outerWidth();
        var newVideoHeight = $('#video-container video').outerHeight();

        $('#video-container video').css({

            'left':     '0px',
            'top':      '0px'
        });

        if(newVideoWidth > windowWidth){

            $('#video-container video').css('left', ((windowWidth-newVideoWidth)/2)+'px');
        }

        if(newVideoHeight > windowHeight){

            $('#video-container video').css('top', ((windowHeight-newVideoHeight)/2)+'px');
        }
    }).trigger('resize');
});
```